# Rails devise set flash message from another action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to show devise error message from another action. I have Registrations Controller with subscription action.

I would like to show error message from my subscription action when the user has already signed up. So this is kind a update of existing user, but without password, just validation for attributes.

If validation fails devise shows error message via subscription action.
By default when the user get updated error message is rendered via update action.

I assume I need to reuse the code from Registrations Controller update action and apply this code to my subscription action, but no luck. Can anyone help to make to show error message from subscription action?

[here devise registrations controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should create a separate controller `SubscriptionController` which contains `new` and `create` (RESTful actions?) which enable you to display a form where you accept the user details and process it, respectively.

Here, in the `SubscriptionController`'s `create` action, you can append errors to the `flash` hash provided by the `ActionController`.

```
class SubscriptionController < ActionController
  def create
    flash[:success] = 'User Registered Successfully'
  end
end
```

In your view(layout), you can have something like this:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <div class="flash">
     <%= msg %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

which will allow you to display the flash message.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I was looking for.

Comment: So, what are you looking for ?

Comment: When user tries to sign up and validation fails he gets message "1 errors prohibited this user from being saved...". This message is triggered from Registrations Controller create action. The same happens for update action when user tries to update his profile. Now, I have attribute coupon_id for which I have validation, however different action (neither create nor update), so I don't get this message telling that validation has failed. I want to have this message displayed via subscription action (like update). As I already told I assume that code from update action could be reused.

Comment: do you have the `<%= f.error_messages %>` in your markup? It allows you to display the validation error messages that are present for the corresponding form model

Comment: Oops. Apparently `f.error_messages`  has been removed. You could try something which is suggested here: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3